# Using ResponseEntity to get Http Response

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created a class with that contains these line of code below.

```
private String app_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
private String app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
private String appKeySecret = app_key + ":" + app_secret;
private byte[] bytes = appKeySecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
private String auth = Base64.encode(bytes);

private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

private Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials")
        .get()
        .addHeader("authorization", "Basic " + auth)
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I also have a controller with a Get Mapping that looks like this

```
  @GetMapping("/auth_token")
public ResponseEntity<MpesaAuth> getToken(@RequestBody Mauth mAuth){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(mpesaAuth, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But when I test the endpoint on post man I get the following error

```
    "timestamp": "2019-09-25T17:26:07.522+0000",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.findfix.payment.config.Mauth> com.findfix.payment.controllers.PaymentController.getToken(com.findfix.payment.config.MpesaAuth)",
"path": "/api/mypayment/v1/auth_token"
}
```

What could I be missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get` method will not have the body, so remove `@RequestBody Mauth mAuth` from `getToken`

```
@GetMapping("/auth_token")
public ResponseEntity<MpesaAuth> getToken(){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(mpesaAuth, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If you want to pass body the you need to use `@PostMapping` or `@PutMapping`

```
@PostMapping("/auth_token") // or @PutMapping
public ResponseEntity<MpesaAuth> getToken(@RequestBody Mauth mAuth){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(mpesaAuth, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

Comment: I worked but now I am getting this error.`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhance
`  I have tried to add `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)` but it doen,t work

Comment: that's a different error and i'm not sure why you are getting that @BrianO